# Trigonometric Integration Problem:

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given that $$f(t)=\begin{cases}-1 & -\frac{T}{2}\leq t \lt 0, \\ +1 & \ \     \ \ 0 \leq  t \lt  \frac{T}{2}\end{cases}$$

Show the steps involved such that $$\frac{2}{T}\int_{t=-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}f(t)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kt}{T}\right)\mathrm{d}t = \frac{4}{T}\int_{t=0}^{\frac{T}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kt}{T}\right)\mathrm{d}t$$ Where $k \in \Bbb{N}$ and $T \in \Bbb{R}$.

An attempt:
$$\frac{2}{T}\int_{t=-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}f(t)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kt}{T}\right)\mathrm{d}t = \frac{2}{T}\int_{t=-\frac{T}{2}}^{0}f(t)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kt}{T}\right)\mathrm{d}t+\frac{2}{T}\int_{t=0}^{\frac{T}{2}}f(t)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi kt}{T}\right)\mathrm{d}t$$

If someone could please show me the steps involved to complete this proof it would be most appreciated.

Many thanks,

Blaze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equality comes from the fact that if $g$ is an even function, then
$$
\int_{-a}^a g(t)\,dt=2\int_0^a g(t)\,dt.
$$
Either draw a figure or write the integral as $\int_{-a}^0+\int_0^a$ and make the substitution $t\mapsto -t$ in the first integral to see that.

The second one is just calculating the integral using the fundamental theorem of calculus, using the facts that
$$
\cos 0 = 1\quad\text{and}\quad \cos(k\pi)=(-1)^k\ \text{if}\ k\in\mathbb N.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understand the second part of your proof completely. But for the first part you said that:  The first equality comes from the fact that if $g$ is an even function,
 then $$ \int_{-a}^a g(t)\,dt=2\int_0^a g(t)\,dt. $$ Glad you made that edit, I wondered if it was a typo. I have made an edit to my post in accordance with what you suggested could you please complete the proof?

Comment: In the first of the two integrals, you write $u=-t$. Then you will get $\frac{2}{T}\int_0^{T/2}f(-u)\sin(-2\pi k u/T)\,du$. Now, $f(-u)=-f(u)$ since $f$ is odd, and $\sin(-2\pi k u/T)=-\sin(2\pi k u/T)$ since sine is odd. Multiplying, you get two minuses, and thus $\frac{2}{T}\int_0^{T/2}f(u)\sin(2\pi k u/T)\,du$, i.e. the same as the second integral.

Comment: and since $u$ is just a "dummy variable" we can just replace it with $t$ right? Such that $$\frac{2}{T}\int_{u=0}^{u=\frac{T}{2}}f(u)\sin(\frac{2\pi ku}{T})\mathrm{d}u=\frac{2}{T}\int_{t=0}^{t=\frac{T}{2}}f(t)\sin(\frac{2\pi kt}{T})\mathrm{d}t$$ is that it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is it. These are the types of calculations that one, if not before, will get very used to when doing Fourier series.

Comment: Since you have been such a great help on this post perhaps you would like to earn some decent rep on this related question on Fourier that immediately follows from this post. Here is the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430436/trivial-fourier-series-for-square-wave-function good luck

Comment: I think the reply you have got is very good, and I don't know how to put it differently... I will have another look in a while to see if it is resolved...